# Matlab, Find cell elements

Tags: string, matlab, find, cell

I have two cell arrays of string A and B. All cells of B are also in A. I want to find the index of cell of B in A. Thanks.

Example:

```
A=
 'aaaa'
 'bbbb'
 'cccc'
 'dddd'
 'ffff'

B=
 'ffff'
 'aaaa'

ans=
  5
  1
```

or

```
ans=
  1
  5
```

Comment: `ismember`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use either `intersect` or `ismember`

```
[~, idxInA] = intersect(A,B)
```

or

```
LocInA = find(ismember(A,B))
```

Comment: You would need `find(ismember(A, B))` to get the specified answer.

Comment: I agree, I have changed it... therefore intersect is nicer :D

Comment: +1 good answer. I did not know the intersect function returned indices.

Comment: But also the second output of `ismember` would work if there are no repeats in `A`: `[x, y]=ismember(B,A)`

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if a member occurs multiple times. Sure it will say which indices had a match, but you will not know which one had a match, or how many times it was matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really simply, use the code below

```
indices = cell(size(B));
for i = 1:numel(B)
    indices{i} = find(strcmpi(A,B(i)));
end
```

While I do recommend using `ismember` or `intersect`, those solutions will not handle case insensitive solutions. Also, those methods will not indicate how many times a specific index was matched, where my solution, will return all indices that match for each comparison.

**UPDATE**

Code I am running to test this.

```
A={'aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','ffff','aaaa'};
B={'ffff','aaaa','cccc','qwerty'};
indices = cell(size(B));
for i = 1:numel(B)
    indices{i} = find(strcmpi(A,B(i)));
end
indices
```

Which returns the following

```
indices = 

    [5]    [1x2 double]    [3]    [1x0 double]
```

I do not see where you are having problems

Comment: How is this easy if you can use `ismember` or `intersect`?

Comment: both are easy. It was a quick solution with no research whatsoever. But I do agree that `ismember` and  `intersect` are better suited for this, unless you want to find matches that are case insensitive

Comment: @Fatime how does it not work, please explain so I can edit it to make sure it does

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Thanks. I think there is a problem if the result of find is empty.

Comment: @Fatime It does not have a problem when there is no match? I ran it with a member that did not have a match, and did not have a problem, I have updated my code above to show exactly what I am running. What version of MATLAB are you running, maybe that has something to do with it? I don't know.

Comment: @MZimmerman6.In your first solution you didn't use cell and there was a problem but the problem has been solved because of using cell.BTW, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Glad I could help. Yeah I noticed the cell issue shortly after I posted the first revision of this answer.